# Android get only the headers for an http request

Tags: android, http-headers, android-networking

Is it possible to send off an HTTP Request in Android to only receive the headers? Similar to the behaviour of `curl -I`? 
I want to get the content-length of a file before the user decides to download it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, do an HTTP Request with a HEAD method (as opposed to POST or GET). It will only work when the server supports it.